# Not able to load .php template via ajax

Tags: templates, jquery-load

```
    userBarToggle.click(function() {
        $('#user-menu').load('wp-content/themes/mytheme/lib/inc/template/user-menu.php');
    });
```

I get 500 Internal Server Error. Any suggestions why?

- Button works perfectly
- Path is correct
- `#user-menu` exists
- Template has `PHP` & `HTML` code in it

---

Also, is there a way to cut off the `wp-content/themes/mytheme/` part? I get 404 without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path is correct, then it should be something wrong with user-menu.php. Did you try erasing everything in that file and return just some text? Also, check the file permissions for it.